# Can Moodle deal with more than 100.000 users?

Tags: load, moodle

I'm working for an e-learning site. I started just a month ago. I'm running a project that involve no more than 5000 users, using Moodle.

They offered me to setup a Moodle plataform for more than 100.000 users, and I don't know if is possible to handle that amount of users using Moodle.

Does anyone knows if is possible to do it? It depends more on the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100.000 simultaneous users or distributed over a month or...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. The hardware determines your capacity, not Moodle itself, which scales very well. We run an instance with 80,000 users and have larger ones coming online soon. You'll just need powerful servers and maybe a frontend load balancer, although we've not needed that yet. One monster frontend server with 8 CPUs and 16GB RAM will handle about 400 users concurrently (requests being processed at the same precise time) if you have the DB on a different machine. Note that Moodle often uses 'concurrent' to mean 'within a single 5-minute period', so this can be confusing.

See [here](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Performance_recommendations#Scalability) for a more detailed discussion of hardware and performance and a link to a list of very large Moodle installs.